# python forward email to specific outlook folder win32com

Tags: python, outlook

I want to forward an Outlook email to a specific folder (not Inbox) using python. I'm using win32com.

When I Forward then Move, my email does appear in the specific folder, but when I look in my Outlook the Datetime and From are not showing.

How do I get the Datetime and From onto the forward/moved email?

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1)
sub_folder1 = root.Folders['Project1']
next_level = sub_folder1.Folders['ProjectA']

msg = next_level.Items
msgs = msg.GetLast()

dest = sub_folder1.Folders['ProjectB']
NewMsg = msgs.Forward()
NewMsg.Move(dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're making a draft of the original received email.

To simply move the email remove the `NewMsg = msgs.Forward()` line  and replace `NewMsg.Move(dest)` with `msgs.Move(dest)`.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1)
sub_folder1 = root_folder.Folders['Project1']
next_level = sub_folder1.Folders['ProjectA']

msg = next_level.Items
msgs = msg.GetLast()

dest = sub_folder1.Folders['ProjectB']
msgs.Move(dest)
```

If you wish to make an actual copy and move the new item to the second folder, replace your ending code with

```
msgcopy = msgs.Copy()

dest = sub_folder1.Folders['ProjectB']
msgcopy.Move(dest)
```